# Why testing mysql 8 procedure with cursor returning data riased error?

Tags: mysql

I try to write mysql 8 procedure with cursor returning data :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getBranchesWithDepartments $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `getBranchesWithDepartments` ( IN  branchId smallint unsigned,  OUT branch_id smallint unsigned, OUT branch_name  varchar(100) )
SQL SECURITY DEFINER

BEGIN

    DECLARE branch_id smallint unsigned;
    DECLARE branch_name varchar(100);

    DECLARE  branchesCursor cursor for SELECT branches.id, branches.name FROM branches
    WHERE branches.active = 1
    AND (  branchId IS NULL OR  branches.id = branchId )
    ORDER BY branches.id;

    open branchesCursor;
    branchesLoop: loop
        fetch branchesCursor into branch_id, branch_name;

       -- debugging
       SELECT concat('branch_id is ', branch_id);
       SELECT concat('branch_name is ', branch_name);

    end loop branchesLoop;
    close branchesCursor;


 END$$
```

I wrote small procedure for testing the procedure above :

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TEST_getBranchesWithDepartments $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `TEST_getBranchesWithDepartments` ()
SQL SECURITY DEFINER

BEGIN

DECLARE  branch_id smallint unsigned;
DECLARE  branch_name  varchar(100);


call getBranchesWithDepartments(null, branch_id, branch_name);
 END$$
```

Both procedures were compliled ok.

But running sql for testing :

```
call  TEST_getBranchesWithDepartments
```

I got error :

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

Reason:
SQL Error [1329] [02000]: No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
```

What can be wrong here and how can I debug my getBranchesWithDepartments procedure ?

**Updated Procedure:**

```
DELIMITER $$


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getBranchesWithDepartments $$


CREATE DEFINER=`lardev`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `quizzes`.`getBranchesWithDepartments`( IN  in_branchId smallint unsigned,  OUT branch_id smallint unsigned, OUT branch_name  varchar(100) )
BEGIN


DECLARE branch_id smallint unsigned;
DECLARE branch_name varchar(100);
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;


DECLARE  branchesCursor cursor for SELECT branches.id, branches.name FROM branches
    WHERE branches.active = 1
    AND (  in_branchId IS NULL OR  branches.id = in_branchId )
    ORDER BY branches.id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;


    open branchesCursor;
    branchesLoop: loop
        SET @step := 1;
        fetch branchesCursor into branch_id, branch_name;

        -- EXIT LOOP AT END
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE branchesLoop;
        END IF;

        SET @step := 2;
       -- debugging - I see these data in my dbeaver console - any message on new console tab - that is not very convinient
       -- I would like to see message on 1 tab - how can I do it
       SELECT concat('branch_id is ', branch_id);
       SELECT concat('branch_name is ', branch_name);

        SET @step := 3;

    end loop branchesLoop;
    close branchesCursor;



 END$$
```

Actually I need to join data from 2 tables Branches and Departments tables into 1 result set with fields like

- id - id of a Branch or Department table, name - name of a Branch or
  Department table, parent_id - is null for Branches and not null for
  Departments

In this way I need data for tree data with  - id of a Branch(1st level) or Department(2nd level) table.

Please any hints how can I do it ?

Comment: Add a continue handler to leave branchesLoop in case no row was found.

Comment: A tutorial on using cursors in stored procedures should show how to stop the loop when you reach the end of results.

Comment: Also in the example you show, there is no need to use a cursor. Perhaps this is just a prototype and you intend to add logic in the cursor loop. But FWIW, almost every use of cursors in MySQL stored procedures I've seen can be written more easily using straightforward queries.

Comment: Never interfere the objects names! ```DECLARE branch_id smallint unsigned;``` in the procedure body masks ```OUT branch_id smallint unsigned``` in the procedure header. The same for `branch_name`. So SP will return NULLs always. [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/8ppzODpo).

Comment: *how can I debug my getBranchesWithDepartments procedure ?* Insert `SET @step := NNN;` after each procedure line (where NNN is natural numbers, i.e. 1,2,3,...), and look its value after the SP call fails. This allows to understand where the error occures. Then store all parameters related to problematic code line and look at them by the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot I moved next. Please read Updated Procedure:

Comment: @Akina, could you please explain trick with @step(BTW, what @ means at start of the var name) var? How can I use it to help in my debugging?

Comment: Study user-defined variables and their scope.